# My blockchain is stuck, how do I "unstuck" it?

Tags: monerod, blockchain, synchronization, daemon

During the last few weeks a common, reoccurring, question seems to be how to get one's blockchain "unstuck". This guide will, hopefully, provide some assistance in doing so.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that, if you are stuck on block `1288639` (or block `1400001`) or a few blocks later, you are using a wrong, outdated, version and you should upgrade to the latest version, which can be found [here](https://getmonero.org/downloads/). In addition, this won't require a resync from scratch, as the "new" `monerod` will automatically use the blockchain that was used with the previous version and pick up syncing where it left off.

The first step in getting your blockchain unstuck is making sure that no Monero related process is running anymore. Thus, close the GUI by clicking on the `x` and make sure to stop the daemon as well. If you're using the CLI, type `exit` into both `monero-wallet-cli` and `monerod`. Thereafter, use your task manager to check whether all Monero related processes are closed. Alternatively, you could simply reboot.

Now that no Monero related processes are running anymore, delete `p2pstate.bin`. On Windows it can be found in the following directory:

`C:\ProgramData\bitmonero`

Note that, by default, the ProgramData directory is hidden. Therefore, use the explorer to manually navigate to aforementioned directory.

On Linux and Mac OS X:

`$HOME/.bitmonero`

This directory is hidden by default too. On Linux you can use `CTRL + H` to unhide directories (note that this might not work on all Linux distributions), whereas on Mac OS X you can use `cmd-shift-dot` unhide directories.

After you've deleted `p2pstate.bin` you can restart `monerod` / the GUI. If this didn't resolve your issue, please read further and make sure `monerod` / the GUI is closed again.

We're going to add the following flag:

`--block-sync-size 10`

This will change the batch of fetched blocks from 20 to 10.

You can add the flag as follows:

If you are using the GUI, simply add `--block-sync-size 10` as daemon startup flag. You can do this on the `Settings` page of the GUI. Note that you'll have to restart the GUI + daemon for the flag to take effect. Thus, add the flag, exit the GUI and stop the daemon as well, and lastly restart the GUI + daemon.

If you are using the CLI, please see below.

On Windows make sure to launch it from the command line. Go to the folder monerod is located and make sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files. Subsequently do SHIFT + right click and it will give you an option to "Open command window here". Lastly, type the following command:

`monerod --block-sync-size 10`

On Linux and Mac OS X you should use the terminal to launch `monerod`. Note that this has to be done from the directory monerod is located in. The command is as follows:

`./monerod --block-sync-size 10`

If your blockchain is still stuck after adding this flag, please browse again to `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` (Windows) or `$HOME/.bitmonero` (Linux and Mac OS X), open `bitmonero.log` and check it for any errors. If you see any of these errors (or similar to them), your blockchain is most likely corrupted and you need to resync from scratch.

`Error opening database: Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid`

`Failed to parse and validate tx from blob` (per MoneroMooo: This *can* be a corrupt blockchain, if this comes from a block inside the db. However, it's much more likely to be an old version not knowing about a new fork)

This is done by deleting `data.mdb` from `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` (Windows) or `$HOME/.bitmonero/lmdb` (Linux and Mac OS X), which will trigger the resync.

Comment: Stuck user here. First, check the logs, they will tell you if there is a problem. I followed all above solutions without checking the logs first and guess what? Half of all entries in the logs says that my db was corrupted. Simply, stopping everything and deleting db solved the issue. When I started again, it started from scratch but at least it's synching again.

Comment: I hate getting up in the morning only to find out the block height hasn't moved one bit ... this worked well, `monerod` would get stuck at 144xxxx and would report 100%, deleting `p2pstate.bin` got it unstuck.

Comment: After couple hours reading blockchain from bootstrap file stuck and I searched for `p2pstate.bin` as described here, but looks like I don't have one, so in my case I never ran monerod after the installation.. so my next step was to run `./monerod` which solved the problem for me: synced to 14xxxxx block(in about an hour or so) and then SYNCRONIZATION (496390 blocks bhind)

Comment: @AlPo - To be clear, the sync is functioning properly now right?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE, worked for me. Don't forget to set `monerod.conf` to tell it where is your `data-dir` located. For example if your lmdb folder located in /home/user/.bitmonero/lmdb then you should set your data-dir=/home/user/.bitmonero/ Also you can set `log-file=/home/user/monerod.log`

Comment: All right, good to hear.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE, Its like this: 1) `monero-blockchain_import --input-file /location/of/your/blockchain.raw --data-dir /location/of/your/monero_blockchain_folder/` which will sync to `1 4xx xxx` block and when it stuck press `Ctrl+c` 2) Set `/home/user/.bitmonero/bitmonero.conf` to tell `./monerod` about `data-dir=/location/of/your/monero_blockchain_folder/` and `out-peers=64` to speed up the 2nd part of sync 3)`./monerod --config-file /location/of/your/bitmonero.conf` (by default `~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.conf`) Note that you download `blockchain.raw` (around 50GB) but this method will sync only 79%

Comment: @AlPo - Importing the blockchain.raw file should normally result in the user having downloaded and verified 99% of the blockchain. Perhaps the process got, for some reason, stuck on your system?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE, problem to sync after block `1 4xx xxx` with usual monero-blockchain-import. I guess right now the only workaround: to sync the rest(less than 24hours) from the internet. If you know how to do it better please feel free to share =)

Comment: Like I said, it should normally run to the end. The fact that it didn't on your system may indicate an idiosyncratic issue. Did you see any errors in the log?