# Problem with speed of synchronization

Tags: synchronization

I have mined 0.1 Monero on MinerGate and since yesterday am transferring it to the wallet. After 24 hours it's got about 20% ... Is this slowness normal ..? It will take about 5 days to finish the transfer.

Comment: Please try this: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your hardware and its bottlenecks.

With the <s>current</s> 0.10.3.1 release, monerod downloads a lot more data than needed. This could be a bottleneck in your case. Current master version (and the <s>soon-to-be-released</s> 0.11) <s>will</s> use up a lot less.

If your CPU does not have hardware AES-NI, block hash verification will be a lot slower.

If you have a hard disk (instead of a SSD), writes will be a lot slower. For this.

One good thing to try is to run monerod with `--block-sync-size 20`, it might well help sync speed. Running current master will also help (it includes this for recent blocks).

Comment: With the current 0.11.* releases, block sync size is now lowered to 100 for the earlier blockchain, then 20. It also downloads not much more than needed, a huge improvement over 0.10.3.1.