# Can't find $HOME/.bitmonero in MacOS

Tags: blockchain

I tried searching "$HOME/.bitmonero" and just ".bitmonero" in my finder window and then pressing command+shift+. but I can't find anything...?

Comment: Everytime I start Monero GUI after a few days, it takes a few hours to load so was just trying out this user guide to try to solve this issue: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it

Comment: It's probably hidden. Did you try to google how to unhide folders on Mac OS X?

Comment: read [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5934/10861) to find out

Answer (score 2):

In finder hold down cmd and shift then the period.  The period toggles hidden files that start with a '.' like '.bitmonero'.

Answer (score 2):

`$HOME` is a variable holding the path to your home directory. `$HOME` is the name of the variable, but what we want is its value. In your terminal, you can type `echo $HOME` to find the value of this variable. Then you can navigate to this directory with your finder. On MacOS it should be something like `/Users/[your-username-here]`.

By typing literally `$HOME` in your finder, you searched for a directory with `$HOME` in it, not the value of this variable.