# Monero GUI goes from connected to still downloading?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am having fits with this monero wallet.. got the right program so that is not the issue.  It will show me connected, but no balance.  then it will go back to downloading blocks.  What the heck..this is day 4.  Is there another way to get the blockchain downloaded.  Trying to use  monero-gui-win-x64-v0.11.1.0.  I have an older computer and low internet speed. Plus I am not that computer talented.

Comment: You could try importing the blockchain to speed up the process

Comment: Also you could consider using a remote node instead of downloading the blockchain yourself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My blockchain is stuck, how do I "unstuck" it?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is the size of the blockchain. As each new block is solved and added to the chain, it grows in size. You are caught in somewhat of a (winnable) race condition: The Monero blockchain is set to dynamically adjust difficulty such that a new block is minted approximately once per minute. Each minute that goes by while you're downloading the blockchain, another block has been added to the chain. In essence the finish line is moving slowly and steadily away from your computer, as it runs to catch up. The biggest factors in how long it takes to catch up is your download speed, and the upload speed of the node you're syncing your wallet or daemon with. One thing you can do to speed up the process is to download a copy of the blockchain, and import it, giving your wallet client a "head start" in essence.

Answer (score 0):

So there is the thing: It really takes a lot of time to download the whole blockchain. But that's needed, so there is no way around it.

After the blockchain was downloaded completely, you will see the status `connected` but after some time it will start downloading again because in the meantime new blocks got generated from new transactions that came up on the blockchain.

So to have the whole blockchain again, the wallet will need to download these new blocks again. That's why it will start downloading again after some time.

If you don't want to mess around will all that, you could use an online service to store your Monero. You will still get the private key and you will have the benefit that you don't need to download anything.

See the [MyMonero website](https://mymonero.com)