# Monero GUI wallet stuck/increasing while syncing blockchain

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, synchronization

Monero GUI wallet stuck/increasing while syncing blockchain

I downloaded the Monero GUI wallet and have been attempting to sync the blockchain for a couple of days now. I left it overnight with about 40000 blocks remaining and upon checking it the next morning I found that the download hadn't completed and in fact the amount of Daemon block remaining had increased.

I found a similar problem online and followed a guide to try and rectify the issue but unfortunately this didn't work. ([My blockchain is stuck, how do I "unstuck" it?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it)). I have also checked that I have the most up to date version.

When I check the logs the error below keeps appearing:

```
2018-05-19 19:35:42.722 464 INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:185   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
    2018-05-19 19:35:44.019 464 ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
    2018-05-19 19:35:56.240 7152    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:185   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
    2018-05-19 19:35:56.240 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:280 Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.0.0-master-release)
    2018-05-19 19:35:56.240 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:53    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
    2018-05-19 19:35:56.240 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:58    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
    2018-05-19 19:35:56.240 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
    2018-05-19 19:35:58.230 5528    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:185   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
    2018-05-19 19:35:58.806 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68 p2p server initialized OK
    2018-05-19 19:35:59.514 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63 Initializing core RPC server...
    2018-05-19 19:35:59.514 7152    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:76 Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
    2018-05-19 19:35:59.514 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:69 core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
    2018-05-19 19:35:59.514 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:86    Initializing core...
    2018-05-19 19:35:59.514 7152    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:427 Loading blockchain from folder C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb ...
    2018-05-19 19:35:59.728 7152    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:525 Loading checkpoints
    2018-05-19 19:36:00.974 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:92    Core initialized OK
    2018-05-19 19:36:00.974 7152    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:74 Starting core RPC server...
    2018-05-19 19:36:00.974 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:79 core RPC server started ok
    2018-05-19 19:36:00.996 5528    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Height: 1536049/1536049 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 1.08 GH/s, v6 (next fork in 13.8 days), up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 1s
    2018-05-19 19:36:01.019 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:78 Starting p2p net loop...
    2018-05-19 19:36:02.039 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1386    [1;33m
    **********************************************************************
    The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. This may take a long time to complete.

    You can set the level of process detailization through "set_log <level|categories>" command,
    where <level> is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING).

    Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
    Use "help <command>" to see a command's documentation.
    **********************************************************************
    [0m
    2018-05-19 19:36:03.932 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1579    [1;33m
    **********************************************************************
    You are now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli.

    Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
    **********************************************************************[0m
    2018-05-19 19:36:04.505 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310 [96.43.139.226:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1536049 -> 1565704 [Your node is 29655 blocks (41 days) behind] 
    SYNCHRONIZATION started
    2018-05-19 19:36:05.011 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310 [104.140.201.102:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1536049 -> 1576396 [Your node is 40347 blocks (56 days) behind] 
    SYNCHRONIZATION started
    2018-05-19 19:36:06.611 [P2P4]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1475 [1;34m----- BLOCK ADDED AS ALTERNATIVE ON HEIGHT 1536048
    id: <ba59496e9ffaef4411c11f80e6c9a28bc2a4ac10c9c801b5a0ae7342e56da6e8>
    PoW:    <e63326136952c9dca998cc6093ec8ea27459d6b67b36a9c8bef5540300000000>
    difficulty: 130301137786[0m
    2018-05-19 19:36:06.720 [P2P4]  ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3398 Block with id: <3ff08a3db2b2ce60be823fbf663a09ec7c29aaaeff8cf6fa663ec986de46e51d> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <d3ea8aee3ff02fcf990b12612decdbd5d74cd93d9f93d91db194da91672515e9>
    2018-05-19 19:36:24.073 [P2P6]  ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3398 Block with id: <3ff08a3db2b2ce60be823fbf663a09ec7c29aaaeff8cf6fa663ec986de46e51d> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <d3ea8aee3ff02fcf990b12612decdbd5d74cd93d9f93d91db194da91672515e9>
    2018-05-19 19:36:26.565 [P2P6]  ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3398 Block with id: <3ff08a3db2b2ce60be823fbf663a09ec7c29aaaeff8cf6fa663ec986de46e51d> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <d3ea8aee3ff02fcf990b12612decdbd5d74cd93d9f93d91db194da91672515e9>
    2018-05-19 19:36:28.811 [P2P6]  ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3398 Block with id: <3ff08a3db2b2ce60be823fbf663a09ec7c29aaaeff8cf6fa663ec986de46e51d> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <d3ea8aee3ff02fcf990b12612decdbd5d74cd93d9f93d91db194da91672515e9>
    2018-05-19 19:36:32.406 7792    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:185   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
    2018-05-19 19:36:32.646 [P2P4]  ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3398 Block with id: <3ff08a3db2b2ce60be823fbf663a09ec7c29aaaeff8cf6fa663ec986de46e51d> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <d3ea8aee3ff02fcf990b12612decdbd5d74cd93d9f93d91db194da91672515e9>
    2018-05-19 19:36:32.700 7792    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Height: 1536049/1576396 (97.4%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 1.08 GH/s, v6, up to date, 3(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 33s
```

Has anyone experienced this before and could possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: Probably not a fix, but mine gets buggered up at times.  Doing a clean exit (type exit in the daemon works.  I *think* crtl-c does a clean exit too).  Then re-running seems to help.  Best of luck.